# Laravel/Scrutinizer: The property username does not seem to exist on App\User. Are you sure there is no database migration missing?

Tags: laravel, continuous-integration, scrutinizer

I have this issue from several days in Scrutinizer CI.

I would get ride of it, but don't know how to do. This is the migration script:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->datetime('last_change_password')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And this is my `App\User`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Validator;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * @param int $id the id of the user
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function changePassword(int $id, array $data)
    {
        $rules = [
            'username' => 'sometimes|required|string|min:8|unique:users,username,'.$id,
            'new_password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:8'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $validator->errors()->all();
        } else {
            $object = $this->find($id);
            if (is_object($object)) {
                if (isset($data[ 'username' ])) {
                    $object->username = $data[ 'username' ];
                }
                $object->password = bcrypt($data[ 'new_password' ]);
                $object->last_change_password = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
                $status = $object->save();
            } else {
                $status = false;
            }

            return $status;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param array $data the data to update
     * @return bool
     */
    public function updateRecord(array $data)
    {
        $rules = [
            'username' => 'sometimes|required|string|min:8|unique:users,username,'.$data[ 'id' ],
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $validator->errors()->all();
        } else {
            $id = $data[ 'id' ];
            $object = $this->find($id);

            if (is_object($object)) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    if (in_array($key, $this->fillable)) {
                        $object->$key = $value;
                    }
                }
                $status = $object->save();
            } else {
                $status = false;
            }
            return $status;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: No. But I did restart the project from zero and for the moment I don't have this issues anymore...